# Need to refresh the page each time i deploy a new changes

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps

i am developing a web application using firebase firestore as back end and NoSQL database and angular as front-end i make a lot of update's and change's on my website and each time a change something i need to ask for all the client to refresh the page and it's so ugly to do this so i try to get the main.[hash].js file from the dist folder and compare it with each new version but no succeed also i try to use serviceWorker also nothing and i search for it in stackoverflow and i can't find a satisfied answer for my question how to refresh the page automatically when i deploy a new version to my firebase hosting with angular 7, thank you.

**This is my last try with serviceworker:**

> log-update.service.ts

```
isUpdateAvailable = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('calling isUpdateAvailable');
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && ['localhost', '127'].indexOf(location.hostname) === -1) {
      // register service worker file
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(reg => {
          reg.onupdatefound = () => {
            const installingWorker = reg.installing;
            installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
              switch (installingWorker.state) {
                case 'installed':
                  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                    // new update available
                    console.log('New update available...');
                    resolve(true);
                  } else {
                    // no update available
                    resolve(false);
                  }
                  break;
              }
            };
          };
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('[ERROR]', err));
    }
    console.log('Dev mode...');
  });
```

> app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.logUpdateService.isUpdateAvailable.then(isAvailable => {
      if (isAvailable) {
        alert('New update found !');
      } else {
        console.log('No new update found.');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: w/ firebase: just use a table with a record (like verion) and subscribe to his datachanges, so you use this as trigger to refresh the client.

Comment: Great idea i think about it but how to make it work! how to change the (version) each time i deploy a new one ?

Comment: Never works with service workers on Angular but about firebase if you want to ret rave real time data from firestore you need to call: `this.database.doc("pathToFile").valueChanges()` or `.snapshotChanges()` not `.get()`. Just think this could be a problem.

Comment: it's not about how to read or write data with firebase firestore or listen to any new value or changes, the problem is how i will store data when i deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Workbox](https://github.com/googlechrome/workbox) in my PWA and it works perfectly. With 
[workbox-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-window) you can simply detect new service worker installation and prompt user to restart the application or restart it without user grant. For more detail, I suggest you read [this link](https://medium.com/@webmaxru/workbox-4-implementing-refresh-to-update-version-flow-using-the-workbox-window-module-41284967e79c).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, based on the answer of @Mises and @Vash72 i create a service called
**log-update.service.ts** i add in this service three fun :

> **isAvailable()**
>
> **newVersion()**
>
> **sameVersion()**

Then i add in my dashboard a button that change the state of the field **isAvailable** in firestore database to TRUE and then i call isAvailable function in **main.ts** in the **ngOnInit()** fun and whenever the **isAvailable** field in firestore change to **TRUE** i refresh the page for the client and i set back the field to **FALSE**

**log-update.service.ts** :

```
export class LogUpdateService {
  updateCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Update>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

  }

  isAvailable() {
    return this.afs.collection('update').doc('available');
  }

  newVersion() {
    const newversion: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`update/available`);
    newversion.update({isAvailable: true}).then(res => {
      console.log('Set new version to true');
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  sameVersion() {
    const newversion: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`update/available`);
    newversion.update({isAvailable: false}).then(res => {
      location.reload();
    });
  }

}
```

**update.ts**:

```
export interface Update {
  isAvailable: boolean;
}
```

**main.ts**:

```
this.logUpdateService.isAvailable().valueChanges().forEach(res => {
      // @ts-ignore
      if (res.isAvailable) {
        console.log('refresh');
        this.logUpdateService.sameVersion();
      } else {
        console.log('No update.');
      }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
But there is a problem, if someone close the website and enter again he will find the same things because of the cache and also if some one open the website but the website tab is not active nothing happen too.